# Looking for an example where graph coloring with Welsh Powell algorithm doesn't give the optimal solution.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

It is always stated that the Welsh Powell algorithm for graph coloring will not always give the optimal solution (using the lowest number of colors). I can't come up with an example where this algorithm uses more colors than the optimum number (chromatic number). I have tried drawing out multiple examples but can't come up with a counter example which shows Welsh Powell algorithm uses more than necessary colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with Welsh Powell is the step where we order the vertices by their degree.  Since degree may be arbitrarily increased without changing the chromatic number [as long as it starts greater than $1$], this step may be arbitrarily manipulated.

For instance, a hexagon may be colored with $2$ colors, but if we list opposite vertices first, it will end with $3$ colors.

If you want to force this ordering, we may stick additional vertices to these opposite vertices, giving the hexagon "handles".

That is, with vertex set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$ consider the edge set $\{ab, bc, cd, de, ef, fa, ag, dh\}$.  It will color $a,d$ the same color, after which we require $3$ colors.